# multiple items in container (drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with my drag and drop code. I want to put multiple items (dragged) in three containers (drop), and then return all values put in the container (thanks to `alert(droppableResults);`). But this code only returns the first item dropped, and I went all of the items.
Thanks for your help!

I put code in jsfiddle.net for better understanding.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbyyvt2o/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the `data-r=""` value gets **overwritten** with every **drop**.
This results in only the **last** drop being recorded (**not** the **first** one).

Since `.dropAble` can contain several elements that approach doesn't work. You might however remove the `data-r` attribute from `.dropAble` and add a `data-q` attribute to your`.dragAble` elements. Then you could modify your JS accordingly and it should work fine.

Here is a modified fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vbyyvt2o/4/